# Doing selenium Automation in idea

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea

i'm new to selenium and want to use selenium web drive. 
i'm using a book and they said that,i have to add selenium.jar and common.jar in globe libraries, 
Also he has mentioned that it is available in the same location that Selenium-Server.jar available.

Please tell me how to find those jars?

what are the things that i need to do when i need to do automated testing in idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [5 minutes getting started guide](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted)? And also [this tutorial](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) helped me a lot starting my first Selenium project

Happy happy testing :)